# How to hide "Tags" in Odoo 13 in Documents Module? and still using it

Tags: tags, document, odoo-13

Greeting guys,

My question is:

How to hide the left sidebar - Tags Category in Documents module? "I attached screenshot".
[Hide this but still using it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DirB.jpg)

I am using Odoo 13 SA not erp.

Thank you,
Yousif

Answer (score 0):

I used Access Rights in Documents Module and give every Workspace Read Access > Administrator Access Rights.

And all of the Tags registered in this workspace with Administrator Rights will be hidden.

Regards,

Yousif